# How to make sure iterators do not overpass end()?

Tags: c++, iterator, distance, stdlist

I have been using `advance` on some `iterators`, but I am afraid of a possible leapfrog above `end()`. I would like to make sure my iterators stay between the bounds, I thought of the `distance` but it seems it does not return what I would be expecting (non-positive values when iterators overpass `end()`). How would you make sure there is no leapfrog?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  list<int> mylist;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) mylist.push_back (i*10);

  list<int>::const_iterator first = mylist.begin();
  const list<int>::const_iterator last = mylist.end();

  cout << "The distance is: " << distance(first,last) << endl; // 10
  advance(first, 10);
  cout << "The distance is: " << distance(first,last) << endl; // 0
  advance(first, 1);
  cout << "The distance is: " << distance(first,last) << endl; // 10
  advance(first, 10);
  cout << "The distance is: " << distance(first,last) << endl; // 0

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
The distance is: 10
The distance is: 0
The distance is: 10
The distance is: 0
```

Comment: If you are looking for a way to make C++ iterators safe--sorry, neither C++ nor the STL was designed to be safe. Instead, doing things you shouldn't do with iterators tends to result in "undefined behavior"--i.e. a crash or worse. To paraphrase the answers below, you have to work around this by writing code that doesn't contain bugs ;)

Comment: Thanks for the pieces of advice. I will directly work on the bugs. Still, I accepted Steve Townsend's answer, because I really like the code snippet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

advance() past end() results in undefined behaviour. You are going to have to test as you go per this snippet:

```
  template <class Iter, class Incr>
  void safe_advance(Iter& curr, const Iter& end, Incr n)
  {
    size_t remaining(std::distance(curr, end));
    if (remaining < n)
    {
      n = remaining;
    }
    std::advance(curr, n);
  }
```

You need to think about what happens when you don't move the full amount (`curr` returned as `end()`.

Comment: @wok - you could change `n` to a ref as well, so you can find out how far it moved along each time

Answer (score 8):

It is inefficient to call `distance` or `advance` on anything other than models of `RandomAccessIterator`: the calls are O(n) where n represents the distance.

Also, the `list` is not truly a model of `Sequence` in that its `size` method is not guaranteed to be constant (or even amortized constant), indeed it could perfectly well be O(n).

Looking at the code (and if you cannot use anything else than a `list`) there are therefore two possibilities:

- Don't use advance, move one item at a time and check with `end` at each step.
- Compute the size once and for all at the beginning, then you know how much you can advance before invoking undefined behavior (you can keep a counter on the side, wrap the iterator etc...)

Let's act on this:

```
// Advance one at a time
// replace calls to advance by this function

typedef list<int>::const_iterator const_iterator;

const_iterator safe_advance(const_iterator it, const_iterator end, size_t n)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i != n && it != end; ++i) { ++it; }
  return it;
}


// Precompute size
size_t const size = list.size();

size_t remaining = size;
const_iterator begin = list.begin();

size_t ad = std::min(10, remaining);
advance(begin, ad);
remaining -= ad;

ad = std::min(1, remaining);
advance(begin, ad);
remaining -= ad;
```

It is tedious to keep this count going though...

**EDIT:**

Addressing David's rightful concerns to generalize the solutions:

```
// Advance `it` from n, or up to end
// returns the number of steps that could not be performed
template <typename Iterator>
size_t safe_advance(Iterator& it, Iterator const& end, size_t n)
{
  size_t i = 0;
  for (; i != n && it != end; ++i, ++it);
  return n - i;
}
```

Note that for Bidirectional Iterators, `advance` is usable with negative distances, however this would require bringing in `begin` as well and would become really tedious. As such, I much prefer a second method:

```
template <typename BI>
size_t safe_reverse(BI& it, BI const& begin, size_t n)
{
  for (; n != 0 && it != begin; --n, --it);
  return n;
}
```

And finally, though I won't do it here, it would be good to specialize the templates for `RandomAccessIterator` since those operations can be done in O(1) with such ones.

Comment: I don't think safe_advance is safe without also checking `it!=end`

Comment: It is a bit tedious. Anyway, thanks for the remarks about complexity.

Comment: @MSN: right, I had begun with an `assert` within the for body and decided to be more lenient... but forgot to move the test :)

Comment: +1 Much better than the accepted answer. I would, myself, change the interface so that it modifies the first iterator (as `std::advance` does) instead of returning it. Then the return value could be used to provide the caller with the number of steps that it was actually incremented (or alternatively the number of steps that were not executed when hitting `end`). That would enable users to differentiate when they rigthfully advanced to `end` from when they requested too long a jump. Also, the iterator type should be generic to allow iteration with non-const iterators if so desired.

Comment: @David: I went for the fastest solution to the problem at hand :-) I've added a template version with the interface you proposed.

Answer (score 5):

Distance can't do this. When your container doesn't offer random access, it tries to reach end by advancing start, which will cause havoc when start overtook last.

You have to start from a valid starting point (i.e. by advancing start you can reach last) and check distance before each advance and only advance by an X<=(distance(first,last) in order not to overtake last.

Comment: Thanks, this is common sense.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple. To avoid going beyond `.end()` simply avoid going beyond `.end()`. The situation is no different as in avoiding to use `NULL` pointer etc. Structure your code so that it never happens. E.g. use loops that use conditions like `it != v.end()` etc. Some popular standard library implementations detects these errors and let you know but you should not rely on it, only use it during testing/debugging.

#### UPDATE

If you cannot be sure that you can `advance()` by amount bigger than one, then you simply must not `advance()` by more than one.

Comment: You do not answer the question. The question is about the advance() function. advance() does several increments at once and they may pass beyond end() and leapfrog. After the advance() is done, it may already be too late to test against end().

Comment: @ypnos: The advice still holds, though.  Just don't `advance()` beyond `end()`!

Comment: i believe this should be proper answer. don't `advance` too much.

Comment: I agree, however bugs are not always easy to catch, so never say never. Specifically about `advance`, this is a bit like a fountain, never say "I shall not drink of your water." :')

Comment: In some situtation you cannot avoid it... I downvote because this is not an answer

Comment: @Donotalo: I think that is implied.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: You must avoid going past the end. It is as simple as that. If you go past the end, you are simply <insert the F word here>. You are in the undefined behaviour land, in the lalaland.

Comment: Take this example... I want to parse a string in the format CMD [SIZE] [PARAM], so I've to advance for SIZE as specified to look the next command. But if the string is not well formatted ( and we for some reason can assure it ) I've to check the doing advance( it, SIZE ) is not goind out

Answer (score 3):

For one thing you could also write an iterator wrapper that stores the end iterator and checks critical operations.

For example using boost's `iterator_facade` for brevity and not checking for underflows.

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class Iter>
class checked_iterator:
    public boost::iterator_facade<
        checked_iterator<Iter>,
        typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type,
        typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category
    >
{
    Iter it, end;
public:
    checked_iterator(Iter it, Iter end): it(it), end(end) {} 
    void increment() 
    { 
        if (it == end) { throw std::range_error("checked_iterator: increment beyond end"); }
        ++it;
    }
    void decrement()
    {
        //TODO: this is not checked
        --it;
    }
    bool equal(const checked_iterator& other) const
    {
        return it == other.it;
    }
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::reference dereference() const 
    {
        if (it == end) { throw std::range_error("checked_iterator: dereference end"); }
        return *it;
    }
    void advance(typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type n)
    {
        //TODO: not checked for underflow
        if (std::distance(it, end) < n) { throw std::range_error("checked_iterator: advance beyond end"); }
        it += n;
    }
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type distance_to(const checked_iterator& other) const
    {
        return other.it - it;
    }
    Iter base() const { return it; }
};

//create checked_iterators from containers, could be overloaded for arrays
template <class Container>
checked_iterator<typename Container::iterator> checked_begin(Container& c)
{
    return checked_iterator<typename Container::iterator>(c.begin(), c.end());
}

template <class Container>
checked_iterator<typename Container::const_iterator> checked_begin(const Container& c)
{
    return checked_iterator<typename Container::const_iterator>(c.begin(), c.end());
}

template <class Container>
checked_iterator<typename Container::iterator> checked_end(Container& c)
{
    return checked_iterator<typename Container::iterator>(c.end(), c.end());
}

template <class Container>
checked_iterator<typename Container::const_iterator> checked_end(const Container& c)
{
    return checked_iterator<typename Container::const_iterator>(c.end(), c.end());
}
```

Example test code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    typedef std::list<int> Container;
    try {
        Container v(10);
        checked_iterator<Container::iterator> it = checked_begin(v);
        std::advance(it, 6);
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
        std::advance(it, 4);
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
        const Container& r = v;
        checked_iterator<Container::const_iterator> cit = checked_begin(r);
        std::advance(cit, 11);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

As to implementing a `safe_advance` function, this could also distinguish between random access iterators and others, like `std::advance` for efficiency reasons:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace detail
{
    template <class Iter>
    void safe_advance_aux(
        Iter& it, Iter end, 
        typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type n, 
        std::random_access_iterator_tag
        )
    {
        if (end - it < n) throw std::range_error("advance beyond end (ra)");
        it += n;
    }

    template <class Iter, class Tag>
    void safe_advance_aux(
        Iter& it, Iter end, 
        typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type n, 
        Tag
        )
    {
        for (typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
            if (it == end) throw std::range_error("advance beyond end");
            ++it;
        }
    }
}

template <class Iter>
void safe_advance(Iter& it, Iter end, typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type n)
{
    detail::safe_advance_aux(it, end, n, typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem here.

Don't use `advance` in a way that could result in going past `end`. You would never use increment (a special form of advance) when your current iterator is pointing to end, so similarly you should never use advance unless your code already knows there are enough remaining elements in the container. If you aren't sure, you need to increment one at a time and check for end on each item. `advance` doesn't (and can't) do any checking for you as it would be a performance hit for code that doesn't need that functionality.

Instead, examine your code and figure out WHY a call to `advance` could cause it to run off the end of your container, and fix that problem with your code instead.

A little more context might give us a better chance to help.

Comment: I am reviewing the code in order to find the bug in the more upstream way. My question may not deal with the right problem to debug the code, but I believe it is still relevant. :)