# cpp std::list add new elements with stepping

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I have two `std::list` with objects: `source_list` and `new_list`. The goal is to add objects from `new_list` to `source_list` starting from `position_at_source_to_adding_new_from` and with `steps_between_new`.

The problem with `steps`: `source_list` can be to short and `new_list` can be to large (or `steps` to big) and when doing `std::advance(it, steps_between_new)` iterator can go beyond the range of `source_list` and its will be `undefined behavior`.

How to check iterator before/after `std::advance` to be sure that we are at ranges? And when there is more objects at `new_list` that can be placed with steps between them - need to simple add there objects to the end of source list.

ps. sorry for my english, its hard to explain on not native language. any corrections are welcome to my text. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make sure iterators do not overpass end()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856416/how-to-make-sure-iterators-do-not-overpass-end)

Comment: @Jon no, because, here is the task to find the best method to merge two lists as described, considering the size of both. not only 'how do not overpass end()'.

Comment: So you read the answers to that question and they didn't help?

Comment: @Jon 1) first of all, method described at the suggested thread and accepted by author is not effective, because its use `distance` and give unnecessary counting(moves from list.begin() to list.end()) on each iteration. 2) they interact only with one list. at my questions we have two lists and any of them can finish before the other and this also need to consider. i am trying to write the code with simple `++iterator` suggested by David, but also do not like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `advance`, just call `++iterator` as many times as needed. After each call, compare the iterator to `end()`.